# How to estimate PSD, and time delay of a random signal?

Tags: fft, filters, noise

I'm trying to estimate the power spectrum and time delay for random signals. the signals were taken from two sensors, 10 cm apart. My aim is to estimate the PSD first then estimate the time delay in order to obtain the structure velocity. 
I've tried the traditional way by using matlab built-in functions like fft, xcorr. however the results were not as I expected.
is there a better way to analyse the attached signals please? Does it need filtering?

The signals represent the void fraction data that was measured for 60s with sampling frequency of 1000hz. the time delay expected to be in ms( around 500ms).
[image: SIGNAL1]
[image: SIGNAL2]

1.Cross Correlation
[image: CROSSCORELATION]
2.AUTO_CORRELATION
[image]

3. PSD
   [image]

4.Cross Correlation after subtracting the average
60000 points
[image]

2000 points
[image]

HERE'S THE DATA

[RUN1_P1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jl0fo21gjfbyj14/run1_p1.avr)

[RUN1_P2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r21np9xt71p4m83/run1_p2.avr)

Comment: You've not provided enough information.  What kind of sensors?  What sampling rate? What is the speed of propagation for your signal (how long would it take to travel between the two sensors?)  What is the time scale in the provided diagrams?  What did you expect to see? (provide a diagram)  What results did you see? (provide a diagram.)

Comment: @JRE the post's updated!!.The sensors measures the void fraction in a pipe, the sampling rate is 1000khz, the time expected to be in ms, may be around 500ms. The time scale is ms. the data was collected for 60seconds with sampling rate of 1000 kHz.

Comment: OK.  The cross correlation and your two original diagrams show the problem.  Cross correlating two signals with a DC component gives the result you've gotten.  You need to run your data through a high pass filter to get rid of the DC.  It might be simpler, though, to take the average of the data points for each sensor and subtract that from each data point for that sensor.

Comment: @JRE I’ve never used filters in signal processing; actually I'm beginner in signal processing. Would you please help me to apply the high pass filter for my signal in Matlab. Which frequencies should be cut off??

Comment: Easiest is to do as I described above:  Computer the average for a data set and subtract that average from each point in the data set.  Do that for each data set and you should be good to go.

Comment: @JRE Thanks a lot. I’ve tried it and it seems fine. The only thing now is that the cross correlation plot has the maximum value at lag zero. Not sure how Xcorr works, but it seems it calculate for 2*N lags. For instance if the you have the 10 data point the xcorr will be calculated for 20 lags (-10 to 10)and the maximum value is at lag 0. any suggestion how to identify  the required maximum peak??

Comment: Check and see if you are carrying out the xcorr as in this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16280  Pay special attention to the plotting in that example.  It shows how to get the proper indexes.  In then example, there's an offset of 80 samples, which is shown as -80 in the diagram.  The zero in your diagram should also be in the middle of the diagram.

Comment: Is it possible you are doing the cross correlation with just one data set?  The diagramm looks suspiciously symmetric, and that would also explain the peak at zero.

Comment: @JRE The peak at -25 which is mean the time delay is 0.025 seconds!. This’s not what I expected. It should be at least 0.2 seconds!

Comment: Is your sampling rate really 1000kHz?  That would be 1MHz, but I can't imagine that the diagrams you've posted were generated from data sets with 60 million samples.  You've possibly got problems with the scaling.  I would judge that you are actually using 1kHz (1000 samples per second.)  Post your newest cross correlation please.

Comment: @JRE Sorry the sampling rate is 1000Hz, so the data se is 60000 data point. The cross correlation plots are updated.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the data sets (as a simple list of the values?)  There is something small that we are overlooking, and it would be easiest to find if I could try it myself.

Comment: @JRE The data files are available within the main post now. They can be downloaded from the links run1_p1 and run1_p2!!Thanks for your continuous support.

Comment: 25 seems to be the correct answer.  That would be 25 milliseconds delay.  I checked it using a different program, and double checked it by adding 1000 samples to the beginning of one data set.  I ended up with 1025 as the delay.  You've done the math correctly.  If the numbers are wrong then there's a problem with the data.  Did you maybe get two data sets from one sensor?

Comment: I thought about this some more.  Maybe your expectation for the delay is wrong.  0.025 seconds over 10 centimeters works out to 4 meters per second, whereas 0.25 seconds over 10 centimeters works out to 0.4 meters per second.  Which value is more reasonable for the system you are working with?

Comment: @JRE Thanks a lot for your help, Could you please double check the PSD of my data and see if it's similar to the graph I posted? As you can see there’re many spikes that almost have same magnitude as the dominant frequency. What I was expecting is one peak (dominant frequency) and small peaks representing the noise. In my system the dominant frequency corresponds to the slugs within the pipe. I have no other phenomenon with such high energy!!.

Comment: I'll check later when I get home, but I seem to remember the peak being way down below 10Hz when I was working on things last night.  I didn't have the resolution set to examine frequencies that far down - I'll look closer this time.

Comment: The peak is around 3Hz, so your PSD is correct.  I also took a look at the waveform.  The two signals are very close to identical, and the 25 millisecond delay is clearly visible.

Comment: @JRE Thanks a lot, it's really appreciated. Have you got the other peaks in the PSD graphs? Do you think the signals should be filtered?? Is it worth it?

Comment: I'm using a dB scaled display (spectrum display in Baudline,) so the lower "peaks" around 3Hz aren't as prominent.  There is a lot of "crap" around 3Hz, though, so I expect the peaks in your plot are OK.

Comment: Could you explain why you were expecting 250 Milliseconds?

Comment: @JRE  It’s just an expectation based on observation of the flow within the pipes (I thought the flow wasn't that fast.. I need to double check different runs and see the trend; if the time delay is proportional to the flow rates then it should be Ok. I’m really grateful for your help, thanks.

Comment: @JRE  I'm back again. I found out that he cross correlation works fine. However I'm having a problem with the frequency values. it's not consistent and not following the expected trend!!(It goes up and down, while it should increase with increasing the flow rates). I'm pretty sure I did the maths write (estimated the autocorrelation and then used fft). Do you think the signal need to be filtered?? could you please suggest any solution. thanks