# What is the best method to estimate the frequency(PSD) for noise signal

Tags: matlab, frequency, power-spectral-density

I’ve been trying to estimate the frequency of a signal I obtained at 1000Hz sampling frequency. The dominant frequency is expected to be not more than 4 or 5 Hz. I’ve estimated the PSD using autocorrelation method however for some signal it seems to noisy and it’s difficult to find the dominant frequency. I’ve tested the method for 60 signals and the output was not as expected (the frequency goes up and down when it should either increase or decrease according to the process).
I shall be grateful for any suggestions
The details of the signal can be found in this post: [How to estimate PSD, and time delay of a random signal?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17701/how-to-estimate-psd-and-time-delay-of-a-random-signal)

here's the code I used

```
%% estimate the power spectral density, where the spectrum is the FFT of the autocorrelation sequence.

for i=1:numel(files)
   N=length(Rxx{1,i}(1:4000));
   nfft{i} = 2^nextpow2(length(Rxx{1,i}));
   % Compute Fourier transform of x using nfft
   Xxx{i} = fft(Rxx{1,i}(1:4000),nfft{1,i});

   % Frequency vector

   fs=1000;
   F{i}= 0 : fs/(nfft{1,i}-1) : fs;

   % Powerspectral density 

   Pxx1{i} =2* abs(Xxx{1,i}).^2/N;     
   [mx{i},ind{i}] = max(Pxx1{i});    
   maxxfreq{i}=F{1,i}(ind{i});    
   figure     
   plot(F{i},Pxx1{1,i}), grid 
   axis([0 10 0 max(Pxx1{1,i})])
   xlabel('Frequency')
   ylabel('Power')
   title('power spectrum')
end
```

Comment: Could you post your matlab code?

Comment: @JRE I've updated my post and added the code. thanks

Comment: Do you require the whole PSD or just the one dominant frequency?

Comment: @jan At the moment the dominant frequency is required. However it would be great if I can get the whole PSD.

Comment: @jan Does the sampling frequency matter, as my sampling frequency is 1000Hz while the maximum dominant frequency seems to be not higher than 4 Hz. 
Could you please suggest a better way to process this signal?

Comment: Could anyone please suggest the best option to estimate the frequency?? is there any need to filter the signal?? I've no experience with filtering!!. Any help is appreciated,